# Laravel with semantic-ui-css icon.woff2 404 not found in heroku

Tags: php, css, laravel, heroku, webpack

When I upload the project to Heroku the icon of Semantic UI not show and I got `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` [image]

But in localhost, it works fine [image]

I have checked the path in CSS file alls looks normal

[image]

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.scripts([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.js',
], 'public/js/app.js');

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

**app.scss**

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Semantic
@import '~semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

// Semantic ui icon
//@import '~semantic-ui-css/components/icon.min.css'; <-- I have try this not work !
```

Also, I add CSS file in the head like

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Do any suggestions please why this happened ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was from a vendor directory in the font folder, I thing Heroku ignore that folder (vendor) for some reason,

The path `fonts/vendor/semantic-ui-css/themes/default` generated automatically by **mix** So what I do is modify `webpack-rules.js` file placed in `node_modules\laravel-mix\src\builder`

```
 rules.push({
        // only include svg that doesn't have font in the path or file name by using negative lookahead
        test: /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/,
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: path => {
                        if (!/node_modules|bower_components/.test(path)) {
                            return (
                                Config.fileLoaderDirs.images +
                                '/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                            );
                        }

                        return (
                            Config.fileLoaderDirs.images +
                            '/' +       //<---------------------  Remove vendor from image path
                            path
                                .replace(/\\/g, '/')
                                .replace(
                                    /((.*(node_modules|bower_components))|images|image|img|assets)\//g,
                                    ''
                                ) +
                            '?[hash]'
                        );
                    },
                    publicPath: Config.resourceRoot
                }
            },

            {
                loader: 'img-loader',
                options: Config.imgLoaderOptions
            }
        ]
    });

    // Add support for loading fonts.
    rules.push({
        test: /(\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$|font.*\.svg$)/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: path => {
                if (!/node_modules|bower_components/.test(path)) {
                    return Config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts + '/[name].[ext]?[hash]';
                }

                return (
                    Config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts +
                    '/' +       //<------------------------- Remove vendo from font path
                    path
                        .replace(/\\/g, '/')
                        .replace(
                            /((.*(node_modules|bower_components))|fonts|font|assets)\//g,
                            ''
                        ) +
                    '?[hash]'
                );
            },
            publicPath: Config.resourceRoot
        }
    });
```

After push project to Heroku all working fine.

**If anyone has a better solution or know why the vendor directory make this issue please explain.**

Thanks for all.